# Firebase push notification in android not working correctly

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am developing an Android application in which I am using Firebase push notifications. Everything is working fine but only one issue with Firebase push notifications.

When my application is open then only big image notification appear ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnI6p.png)).

But when my application is closed the big image notification is not displaying ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOiIV.png)).

**MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.java**

```
 public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
        private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";
        @Override
        public void onTokenRefresh() {
            // Get updated InstanceID token.
            String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
            Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
            sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
        }
        private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        }
    }
```

**MyFirebaseMessagingService.java**

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = "FirebaseMessageService";
    Bitmap bitmap;

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

        //The message which i send will have keys named [message, image, AnotherActivity] and corresponding values.
        //You can change as per the requirement.

        //message will contain the Push Message
        String message = remoteMessage.getData().get("message");
        //imageUri will contain URL of the image to be displayed with Notification
        String imageUri = remoteMessage.getData().get("image");
        //If the key AnotherActivity has  value as True then when the user taps on notification, in the app AnotherActivity will be opened.
        //If the key AnotherActivity has  value as False then when the user taps on notification, in the app MainActivity will be opened.
        String TrueOrFlase = "praveen";

        //To get a Bitmap image from the URL received
        bitmap = getBitmapfromUrl(imageUri);

        try {
//            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.watchicon)
            sendNotification(message,bitmap , TrueOrFlase);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("qwerty", " exception = " + e.toString());
        }

    }


    /**
     * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message.
     */

    private void sendNotification(String messageBody, Bitmap image, String TrueOrFalse) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StartActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.putExtra("AnotherActivity", TrueOrFalse);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ball)
                .setContentTitle(messageBody)
                .setContentText("hello")
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                        .bigPicture(image))
                .setAutoCancel(true);


        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());


    }

    /*
     *To get a Bitmap image from the URL received
     * */
    public Bitmap getBitmapfromUrl(String imageUrl) {

        try {
            URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you sending the push notification ?, using firebase console or do you make a post call ?

Comment: yes from firebase console

Comment: Okay, the thing is that when the app is not running, firebase handles the messages on its own [if you send it from the console]. If you put logs in onMessageReceived, m sure you wont get them after sending notifications. In order to resolve this, you will have to use the firebase apis to do the job. Usually firebase notifications have two components, data and notification. For your use case to work you will have to send notification part as null and pass every thing you need to render in the data part. This way you would get whatever you need to render by parsing the data

Comment: you are saying if i am going to send the notification with firebase api through post method it will work even my activity is closed?

Comment: Yes provided you make sure you send the notification part null and handle the notification using the data part

Comment: oh and if i want to send the notification to all person who had my application install can i do that??

Comment: Yes sir, if you have their tokens

Comment: suppose if i have 10,000 active users i want to send the notification to every user. don't you think putting every one token in the post method is quiet a head ache

Comment: It can accept a list of tokens, have a look at the api https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref

Comment: hi @AshishKumar I just check the notification with api post method. but still the result is the same.

Comment: is your send notification function being called, can you debug that ?

Comment: i just check it there are 2 check point on onMessageReceived function 1)remoteMessage.getNotification() 2) remoteMessage.getData() but i think on messageRecieved is not being called when application in background

Comment: Are you sure you have sent  notification null from the api ?, can you post the json from the logs ?

Comment: but why should i send notification null. when onMessageReceived function is not executed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also getting the same problem while using firebase. The answer is very simple.

1) Register your application on Firebase console and import the necessary library needed.

2)Make services classes MyFirebaseMessagingService and FirebaseInstanceIdService.

3)Register your service to AndroidManifest

4) Now come to MyFirebaseMessagingService.java class and do the modification

```
public class Notif extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            try {
                JSONObject data = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData());
                String jsonMessage = data.getString("body");
                String jsonTitle = data.getString("title");
                String jsonImage = data.getString("image");
                mainNotification(jsonTitle, jsonMessage, jsonImage);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void mainNotification(String title, String body, String image) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder bn = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.analytics)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000})
                .setContentText(body)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                        .bigPicture(getBitmapfromUrl(image)))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(pi);
        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (nm != null)
            nm.notify(0, bn.build());
    }


    public Bitmap getBitmapfromUrl(String imageUrl) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return bitmap;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

5) Make sure that you were sending your notification using post menthod without sending the notification part and sending only **data** part with all the 
header with **Content-Type application/json**
**Authorization key=yourkey**
link where you have to post https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
with body like this

```
 {
      "to": "/topics/NEWS",
       "data": {
           "body":"text",
           "title":"AAAAAAA",
           "image":"https://static.independent.co.uk/s3fs-public/styles/article_small/public/thumbnails/image/2016/11/14/12/messi.jpg"
       }
    }
```

now click send and this will work. already tested

Answer (score 0):

You may get mybitmap null. Try to check it first and to resolve this use `Picaso` with the async task to download an image from url and then in on completion generate the notification with mybitmap.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: see both them image even the small icon is not visible